# Using Microsoft Fakes with 'extern' modifier (DllImport)

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

Currently I have the following class and method that I would like to fake (i.e. shim the class/method):

```
namespace Test
{
   internal static class TestClass
   {

      [DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "TestClass_Start", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern void Start();
   }
}
```

I am aware that the class is internal, I therefore added *InternalsVisibleTo* and so far everything works except this class.

My assummption is that you can't fake extern methods. I found the following in a [thread from 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af0309c3-edb2-4da4-9abc-cc169a4a8f6a/how-to-mock-dllimport-using-shim-or-stub):

> Shimming of extern methods is not supported directly. However, if you
>   wrap an extern method using regular static methods [...]
>   you can shim that method instead.

I totally agree that I could overcome the issue by wrapping the class but my question is different. I could not find any other sources that agree with the thread and I therefore ask:

**Can you shim a extern method (DllImport) with Microsoft Fakes? If no, is there an official source documenting it? If yes, could you please provide an example?**

Comment: The answer appears to be no as I'm running into the exact same issue. Doesn't make sense to me that you can shim the `static` wrapper method but not the `static extern` one. I've submitted a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1039048/unable-to-shim-public-static-extern-methods.html).